# Maven reporting and site generation for multiple module project

Tags: java, maven, surefire

I am trying to get project with submodules to test and generate reports correctly, but have got some problems.

I have the following project structure:

```
parent
  |-test1
  |-test2
```

and the pom.xml for `parent` looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>parent</groupId>
<artifactId>parent</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<modules>
    <module>test1</module>
    <module>test2</module>
</modules>

<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <reportsDirectories>
                    <reportsDirectory>${basedir}/target/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                </reportsDirectories>
            </configuration>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <inherited>false</inherited>
                    <reports>
                        <report>report-only</report>
                    </reports>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

And I use `mvn clean install site` to build the project, run the tests and generate a site (which uses maven site plugin, which in turn uses maven surefire report plugin, to generate test report).

**The trouble is** the parent pom.xml is executed with all phases (clean, install and site) before submodules' pom.xml are executed, hence no test report from `test1` and `test2` are aggregated in `parent`.

So is there a way to execute `mvn clean install site` in a single line, or do I absolutely have to execute `mvn clean install` first then `mvn site`?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The config shown uses the same POM as both the parent and aggregator.  Documentation will also discuss inheritance vs. multi-module.  A parent POM passes values to its children, while an aggregator POM manages a group of subprojects or modules.  Section 3.6.2 of the [Sonatype Maven Book](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html) goes into a lot more detail.

In my experience, Maven builds work better when the parent and aggregator POMs are *separate*.

The reason has to do with dependencies, how Maven determines build order, and how Maven runs commands.  If your sample structure was like this, with a separate parent and aggregator, where test1 and test2 inherited from parent:

```
project (aggregator POM)
  |- parent
  |- test1
  |- test2
```

then the Maven build order will look like this (assuming dependencies are defined correctly of course):

- parent
- test1
- test2
- aggregator

A command like `mvn clean install site` will start with the parent project, cleaning and building, installing to the local artifact repository, then generating the project site. It repeats this command sequence in order for each project shown. Because the aggregator is separate, it may have separate configuration to perform report aggregation for tests, coverage and javadoc. The aggregator runs last, so the coverage databases and intermediate javadoc files for the modules already exist, ready to be appropriately combined.

When the parent and aggregator are the same POM as you have it, the build order is:

- parentAggregator
- test1
- test2

When you run `mvn clean install site` now, Maven must build the parent POM (here, parentAggregator) so it has the information required for the child modules depending on it. parentAggregator is also the aggregator, so Maven will happily run any aggregating reports as part of `site`. Of course, the child modules haven't been built yet, so there are no coverage databases or intermediate javadoc files to aggregate. Or, possibly worse, old files exist so the aggregator operates on those files. After the parent-aggregator builds, the child modules build, and then the command exits. There is no final aggregation step at the end of the build. The overall results are probably not what you want.

This phenomenon can cause problems during multi-module project release builds, painful enough that developers wrote a [versions-maven-plugin mojo](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/update-child-modules-mojo.html) to help correct them. The issue:

> If you have a multi-module build where the aggregator pom (i.e. the one with packaging of pom and the modules section) is also the parent referenced by its child modules, and the aggregator version does not match the version specified in the parent section of the child modules, Maven will not let you build the project.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion about aggregator, which is a good solution to this problem.  And you also correctly predicted "old files exist so the aggregator operates on those files" :)

Comment: Nice answer! Are there best practices concerning naming conventions for aggregator and parent artifacts? (Should the parent folder be `parent` or `root` or `config`? Does it matter at all?)

Comment: Awesome answer. Finally I understand the difference between parent and aggregator. Thank you!